# Unix : delete text matching pattern in a file

Tags: unix

I got a data table that I would like to export in a .csv format. The file currently looks like this :

60: 1 (prob=0.0001,cumulative=0.0001)

63: 2 (prob=0.0001,cumulative=0.0002)

64: 1 (prob=0.0001,cumulative=0.0002)

I only want to keep the first characters (64: 1) of each line and to delete the text between parenthesis. Is there a command to delete this text in every line ??

Comment: [`sed`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpage/sed)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sed`.

```
$ sed -E "s/ \(.+//g" input.txt
60: 1
63: 2
64: 1
```

`-E` sets `sed` to use extended regexps (which are more convenient usually).
The actual expression is a `s`ubstitution, so `sed` looks at each line, finds things matching the regular expression `\(.+`, i.e. a space followed by a literal parentheses, then anything until the end of the line and replaces it with nothing.